# Manage Internet connectivity in the entire app

Tags: java, android, internet-connection

I know the code how to check the Internet connection in the device but i want to how to  manage the internet connection check as my app contain many asnchronours tasks, services etc. means where to show the Internet Error Dialog.

Comment: make single async task class for all calls and check internet connectivity in AsyncTask method onPreExecute

Comment: You could define a global class that checks connection, with a static boolean variable that notifies your entire app when it connected and does the same when not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast action to listen for the connectivity changes on the device.

ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Answer (score 0):

Create a Utility class where add a method to check for the internet availability as follows :

```
 /**
     * method to check the connection
     *
     * @return true if network connection is available
     */
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) MainApplication.getsApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null)
            return false;

        State network = info.getState();
        return (network == State.CONNECTED || network == State.CONNECTING);
    }




/**
     * method to toast message if internet is not connected
     *
     * @return true if internet is connected
     */
    public static boolean isInternetConnected() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // TODO Here write the code to show dialog with Internet Not Available message
......

            return false;
        }
    }
```

And now you can use it before you execute your AsyncTask just add this check

```
if (Utility.isInternetConnected()) {
                // TODO start your asyntask here
            }
```